# Display of differences between revisions

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Being impressed by the [visualisation of differences between revisions](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/325537/revisions) on this site (and MSE as well) I cannot resist to ask: what javascript libraries are used for this? I know that MathJax is used to render mathematical expressions and that there are many javascript diff libraries, but not all of them would play nicely with MathJax.

Comment: here is the revision script: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/revisions.en.js

Comment: I found this question on Meta Stack Exchange, although I am not sure the answers there are satisfactory: [What revision library does stackoverflow use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24313)